# How to set MFMailComposeViewController From field rather than default mail app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to set MFMailComposeViewController From field rather than default mail from field. I am constructing one app which has different email id sign up I want to sync those ids and send mail from those accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can change `From`, since `MFMailComposeViewController` is used to send mail with mail accounts registered in iOS's `settings`, not the mail address you used to login your app.

Comment: So is there any alternative exact similar to MFMailComposeViewController and in which we can change "From" field as per our app sign up email ids

Comment: @SurajSS if the user didn't provide his email password to your app, there is no way to send mail on his behalf

Comment: No i am having users email Id and password already sign in. Actually my app is having different account users added there service account it may be 4-5 any no of account.I just want to give choice to select 1 account from them and show it to my customised "From" field which MFMailComposeViewController doesn't provides

Answer (score -4):

try this code

```
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender 
{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailer setSubject:@"A Message from MobileTuts+"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fisrtMail@example.com", @"secondMail@example.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mobiletuts-logo.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
    [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"]; 

    NSString *emailBody = @"Have you seen the MobileTuts+ web site?";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];


}
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}
```

for check result

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }

        // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: but how to change "from" field of mail?